# Simplify printf

Tags: java

```
  System.out.printf("%7s", "a");
  System.out.printf("%7s", "b");
  System.out.printf("%7s", "c");
  System.out.printf("%7s", "d");
```

Just want give for string 7 spaces. Is there a better way for printing it without 4 new `printf()`'s?

Comment: why not `System.out.print("      a      b      c      d")`?

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger: I am too cool for that.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
System.out.printf("%7s%7s%7s%7s", "a", "b", "c", "d");
```

Answer (score 3):

You are printing a...d

```
   char first = 'a';
   char second = first + 1; // will be b
```

so you can use a for loop and avoid repetition